# Filter cells of multiple columns by one value Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I searched everything but could not find a solution to solve the following problem:
I have multiple columns and the cells of the columns can have the following values: Empty, "W", "A", "S"

And now I want to filter the rows by one cell - so if I put "W" into my "search-cell" there should be only the rows visible where there is the value "W" in one cell of the columns

So before filter:

[image: Before Filter]

And after filter:

[image: After Filter]

Is this possible without vba ?

Comment: Without VBA, you would need a helper column which simply checks if the searchstring is in its own row. then just filter it by the helper column...

Comment: To have it *automatically* filter (with absolutely no manual intervention after entering the search term) is **not** possible with VBA. If you are willing to enter the search and filter 1 column, you can do this with a helper column containing a formula.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: isn't it possible to add some filtering code in a 'Worksheet_Change' event handler?

Comment: You could possibly attempt to use `Advance Filter` in excel.

Comment: I allready tried the advanced filter function with no success - but I think I will do it with a value change event - thanks for the idea ;)

Comment: @user3598756 - yes, of course. I mis-typed. I meant to say **without** VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is just for scott :P

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastRow As Long, varArr As Variant, val As String, rowArr(1) As Range, i As Long
    val = LCase(Me.Range("F1").Value2)
    Me.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Len(val) Then
      lastRow = Application.Max(Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
      varArr = Me.Range("A1:D" & lastRow).Value2
      For i = 3 To lastRow
        If val = LCase(varArr(i, 1)) Or val = LCase(varArr(i, 2)) Or val = LCase(varArr(i, 3)) Or val = LCase(varArr(i, 4)) Then
          If rowArr(0) Is Nothing Then
            Set rowArr(0) = Me.Rows(i)
          Else
            Set rowArr(0) = Union(rowArr(0), Me.Rows(i))
          End If
        Else
          If rowArr(1) Is Nothing Then
            Set rowArr(1) = Me.Rows(i)
          Else
            Set rowArr(1) = Union(rowArr(1), Me.Rows(i))
          End If
        End If
      Next
      rowArr(0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
      rowArr(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End If
End Sub
```

(search field is F1 and case doesn't matter)

Comment: Ugh. I just re-read my comment. I mis-typed. I meant to say it's not possible **without** VBA!

Comment: Thank you - I will make it with this approach !